# JSON sent from C# but not received as JSON in php

Tags: c#, php, json

My purpose is to send JSON from C# to PHP and then further decode it on PHP side to use it for my purpose.
Error at PHP end is:

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home3/alsonsrnd/public_html/test/sync.php on line 24

I am using the following code to send JSON to my PHP code using C#:

```
  private void sendData()
     {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://alnnovative.com/test/sync.php");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"user\":\"test\"," +
                          "\"password\":\"bla\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

On PHP I am using strip slashes and json_decode() in order to decode JSON. My PHP code gives error that the received string is an array instead of JSON and thus it cannot use json_decode to decode it. What could be the reason of it? As I am sending the correct format of JSON from C#

My PHP code is:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $json=$_POST;
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $json = stripslashes($json);
    }

    //Decode JSON into an Array
    $data = json_decode($json);
}
```

Comment: It is present in the code. string json=.....

Comment: Is it a typo - http://screencast.com/t/7bc2MCQpzko4? Seems names of variables not match.

Comment: Can you add a debug line on your PHP server to print out the JSON it receives? (Before and after the slash stripping)

Comment: Can we see the PHP code?

Comment: @Vnuuk yes it was a typo in the question, i have changed it.

Comment: @Rinecamo I have added my PHP code.

Comment: @Rob When I am printing it via var_dump() and print_r() it gives Array()

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899033/php-how-to-read-post-data-with-no-key

Comment: $_POST is an array, it is not your JSON

Comment: @Random yes that is the problem. When I am sending JSON, why it is received as an array?

Comment: Have a look at @Rinecamo comment, it shows you how to read the $_POST variable. $_POST may contain multiple variables, so it is an array (even if the array contains 1 item in your case)

Comment: $_POST ist always an array (or rather a dictionary), that's just how it works. Try giving your json string a key ex. `string json = "json={...}";` and read it with `$_POST['json']`

Comment: I have fix for your situation - instead of WebRequest you can use WebClient - http://screencast.com/t/1rjmTOdt

Comment: I tested your solution with my ASP.NET client - it doesn't work on my end. And then I've tested solution with WebClient - and it receives correct user and password.

Comment: @Vnuuk I have tested with webClient too, but still not receiving anything, just an empty array/

Comment: Yes, there is a problem on PHP side then..

Comment: Look at the first answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000386/post-array-empty-on-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: Now I get NULL as the result when I use $data = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
var_dump($data);

Comment: Hm.. Can you see what you send from C# side via fiddler?

Comment: Yes, I can see the same JSOn being sent, when I see it on Debug

Comment: @Vnuuk result variable gives: "...object(stdClass)#3 (2) {\n  [\"user\"]=>\n  string(4) \"test\"\n  [\"password\"]=>\n  string(3) \"bla\"\n}\n<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in <b>/home3/alsonsrnd/public_html/test/sync.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />\n[]"

Comment: So we receive json in php? Now you need to parse it, right?

Comment: But when I print the posted result in PHP, I get NULL

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to change your Content-Type header

```
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Secondly, you are sending data in wrong format

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "json=" + "{\"user\":\"test\"," +
                              "\"password\":\"bla\"}"; ;

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
```

And finally, you are receiving data in wrong way, $_POST is an array, so

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['json']))
{
    $json=$_POST['json'];
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $json = stripslashes($json);
    }
    //Decode JSON into an Array
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
}
```